# Ubuntu 18.04 won't boot after installing steam

Tags: boot, 18.04, steam, libraries

Yesterday I installed steam to play some game. The installation went well. Now as I opened the application it opened the terminal and required me to enter a password so more libraries could be installed. The only thing I remember about these libraries is that one of them had the name `lib-mesa-*` . I turned off my laptop fine and slept. Today in the morning my Ubuntu can't boot. It's either stuck on the screen where services are being started or it gets stuck on the `dev sda clean 12498/49480004737` screen. What can I do to fix my Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to access the tty console using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>. After doing so, I executed the following command.

`sudo apt purge libglapi-mesa`

And it removed a lot of packages related to this library.

Then I reinstalled

`sudo apt install libglapi-mesa`

Then I rebooted my PC and found out that I no longer have a desktop environment. But my WiFi is working anyway. So I grabbed a new copy of ubuntu-gnome-desktop

`sudo apt install ubuntu-gnome-desktop`

It installed successfully and I rebooted my PC and wow it's working. Now I am typing this answer using my ubuntu which I was worried about that I am going to loose all my files and all my projects. I am so happy that I managed to fix this on my own.

It's working... back to coding...

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fool-proof step-by-step solution:

1. Boot into safe mode (recovery mode). Enter this mode by holding the left <kbd>shift</kbd> key when the computer starts.
2. in terminal, type:

   `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*`

   `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` #Make sure you have internet connection

(This worked on my dual booted computer (Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04)

my error message was `/dev/nvme0n1p5: clean, nnn/nnn files, nnn/nnn blocks`

**#cheers**

Comment: When I  execute the first command ```sudo apt purge  nvidia*``` I am seeing 'nvidia-utils-450-server' is not installed,  so not removed. 450,440, 418 etc.

Comment: try installing sudo apt installing nvidia driver using  `--reinstall nvidia-driver-450`  and other as well 
if problem persist then,
Still no driver been built by dkms. I suspect the problem is not with the driver but the kernel did not properly register with dkms on update. Please reinstall the kernel headers `sudo apt install --reinstall linux-headers-5.0.0-31-generic`  and post the output of dkms status afterwards.

Comment: I fixed it, check the answer below.